# Methods UITextField of UISearchBar return nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I've got a searchBar which sometimes has text filled in. I would like to set the cursor of the underlying UITextField to a certain position. I already have a pointer that is not nil to the **UITextField**:

```
UITextField *searchField = [self.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
```

And I fill in the text:

```
self.searchBar.text = addressToComplete.description;
```

And checked if the UITextField text is filled in and it is.
Still, all the methods regarding UITextPosition and UITextRange return nil:

```
UITextRange *selectedRange = [searchField selectedTextRange]; //selectedRange = nil
UITextPosition *newPosition = [searchField positionFromPosition:selectedRange.start offset:addressToComplete.street.length]; //newPosition = nil
UITextRange *newRange = [searchField textRangeFromPosition:newPosition toPosition:newPosition]; //newRange = nil
```

I'm wondering what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're saying `[searchField selectedTextRange]` is returning nil? Probably means nothing is selected, I don't know how the `UITextField` behaves in the case nothing is selected. Your text might be in its place, but that doesn't have anything to do with selection. Try manually tapping and selecting like a word in the `UISearchBar` and then call `[searchField selectedTextRange]` - then it should not return nil I suppose.

Comment: You're right. When I tap in the UISearchBar then the methods do return valid objects. Isn't there anyway to do this pragmatically?

Comment: There is, but I don't think I understand the problem you're solving. You fill the `UISearchBar` with some text and then you want to do what?

Comment: And then I want to set the cursor at a specific point. The text is an address and I want to put the cursor behind the streetName. I already have the right length, but I now need to set the cursor.

Comment: @Michael90: Have u fixed this issue already? Can show me the solution? I also encounter it? Thanks

Comment: @NTNT : no I haven't found a solution yet, It's a small feature that would be more like a easy usage of the app instead of a big deal